# Obtener datos XML al utilizar api con una conexión WS

Tags: java, eclipse

Hola buenos días ayer por la tarde me pidieron que consumiera una api utilizando Java (Eclipse) para poder obtener datos de la api pero antes se hiso el ejemplo del WS con Postman y si se logró obtener los datos XML, ahora lo que estoy intentando es pasar la funcionalidad a Java pero no logro hacer la conexión. Les comparto los datos que se utilizaron en Postman y el código que tengo hasta el momento en Java junto con los errores que me manda.

> Datos utilizados con Postman

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Código Java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class WS_Servnet {
    // http://localhost:8080/RESTfulExample/json/product/post
        public static void main(String[] args) {

          try {

            URL url = new URL("https://sip.serv.net.mx/xmlapi/xmlapi");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");

            String input = "{\"qty\":100,\"name\":\"iPad 4\"}";

            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(input.getBytes());
            os.flush();

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;
            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(output);
            }

            conn.disconnect();

          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

          } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

         }

        }

}
```

> Error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 401
    at WS_Servnet.main(WS_Servnet.java:28)
```

Pueden apoyarme si mi código va bien y que parámetros me falta mandar.

Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

El código 401 de HTTP indica que no se está autorizado a consumir el recurso. Esto te está ocurriendo porque si bien en el PostMan si agregas las credenciales de autenticación, en el código no lo estás haciendo.

Con algo como esto debe ser suficiente (usando `Basic Authentication`):

```
String user = "ABACOM";
String pass = "MiContraseña"
String auth = user + ":" + pass;
byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encode(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

String authHeaderValue = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);

conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authHeaderValue);
```

El código que te mostré lo puede meter en cualquier línea posterior a la creación de la conexción y antes de llamar al método `Connection.getOutputStream()`.

**Actualización**

Para enviar datos en el cuerpo de la solicitud POST debes hacer lo siguiente:

```
String dataXml = "....";

conn.setDoOutput(true);

try(OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream()) {
    byte[] input = dataXml.getBytes("utf-8");
    os.write(input, 0, input.length);           
}
```

Comment: Me marca error en el encodeBase64 "The method encodeBase64(byte[]) is undefined for the type Base64"

Comment: byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

Comment: Que versión de Java usas? Esto es para Java 8 o superior

Comment: Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0) IDE ECLIPSE Version: 2019-09 R (4.13.0) JAVA

Comment: Qué versión de Java es esa? Esa es la versión del Eclipse. Busca que JDK estás usando.

Comment: estoy usando java 8 y para sabe le di en la carpeta de java->acerca de java

Comment: Disculpa, fui yo el que me equivoqué. Ya te actualicé la respuesta con el código correcto

Comment: Me sigue marcando error en el metodo encodeBase64 de Base64

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 401
 at WS_Servnet.main(WS_Servnet.java:43)

Comment: Mira bien el nuevo código. Base64.getEncoder().encode(...)

Comment: Ya lo corregí pero me singue marcando el siguiente error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 401
 at WS_Servnet.main(WS_Servnet.java:43)

Comment: Verifica las credenciales porque eso es problema de permisos sobre el recurso.

Comment: Según yo los datos son corrector, pero mi duda es donde coloco los datos que muestra la imagen 3 los cuales son listAccounts, i_account..

Comment: Yo tengo codigo en el cuerpo con la peticion Postman, entonces yo si lo debo de poner ¿Verdad?

Comment: El mismo XML que tienes en PostMan debe ser el valor de la variable `dataXml`

Comment: Ya lo hice y aun me sigue marcando error, ya intente de varias y no me da